Selección de Idioma en Laravel 11 de manera persistente
¿Cómo poner en idioma seleccionado por el usuario en Laravel 11 de manera persistente, es decir, que mientras el visitante o usuario permanezca en la página y una vez seleccionado un idioma   permanezca en ese idioma aunque cambie de página.?

Console

Instalar paquete de idiomas.
Install language package.

composer require laravel-lang/common --dev
php artisan lang:add es
php artisan lang:add en
php artisan lang:update

App/Http/Controllers/LanguageController.php (new file)

Crear un nuevo controlador con el siguiente código
Create a new controller with this code.

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function switch($lang)
    {
            Session::put([
                'applocale' => $lang,
                'locale' => $lang,
            ]);
            return Redirect::back();
    }
}

App\Http\Middleware\Language.php (new file)

Crear un nuevo nueco middleware con este código
Create a nuew middleware with this code.

<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Language
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $langSesion = Session::get('applocale');
        array_key_exists($langSesion, config('languages')) ? App::setLocale($langSesion) : App::setLocale(Config('app.fallback_locale'));

        return $next($request);
    }
}

bootstrap\app.php

En caso de no haber editado anteriormente, el archivo "app.php" de la carpeta bootstrap quedará así:
In case you have not edited it before, the "app.php" file in the bootstrap folder will look like this:

<?php

use App\Http\Middleware\Language;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->web(append: [Language::class]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();


config\languages.php (new file)

Crear un nuevo archivo llamando "languages.php" en la carpeta config.(en este ejemplo solo hay dos idiomas)
Create a new file called "languages.php" into the config folder.(in this sample there are only two languages)

return $idiomas = [
    'en' => "English",
    'es' => "Español",
];

resources\views_partials\lang.blade.php (new file)

Archivo con el menú, verificando que el el idioma pasado por GET esté entre los idiomas admitidos, en caso contrario devolverá el idioma predeterminado prededermintado.
File menu, verifying that the language passed by GET is among the supported languages, otherwise it will return the default pre-determined language.

@props([
    'idioma' => array_key_exists(session('locale'),config('languages')) ? session('locale') : Config('app.locale'),
])
<ul>
@foreach (config('languages') as $key => $value)
    @if ($key != $idioma)
    <li>
        <a class="inline-flex rounded bg-indigo-500 px-6 py-2 text-lg text-white"
        href="{{ route('lang', $key) }}">{{ $value }}</a>
    </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
</ul>



